# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException occurs when I use map function of DataFrame on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame "orderedDf" , which schema is below:

```
root
|-- schoolID: string (nullable = true)
|-- count(studentID): long (nullable = false)
|-- count(teacherID): long (nullable = false)
|-- sum(size): long (nullable = true)
|-- sum(documentCount): long (nullable = true)
|-- avg_totalScore: double (nullable = true)
```

Here is the data of my DataFrame "orderedDf":

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
|schoolID|count(studentID)|count(teacherID)|sum(size)|sum(documentCount)|avg_totalScore|
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
|school03|               2|               2|      195|               314|         100.0|
|school02|               2|               2|      193|               330|          94.5|
|school01|               2|               2|      294|               285|          83.4|
|school04|               2|               2|      263|               415|          72.5|
|school05|               2|               2|      263|               415|          62.5|
|school07|               2|               2|      263|               415|          52.5|
|school09|               2|               2|      263|               415|          49.8|
|school08|               2|               2|      263|               415|          42.3|
|school06|               2|               2|      263|               415|          32.5|
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
```

As we can see that the column "avg_totalScore" is ordered by desc.
Now, I have a problem, I want to partition the all the rows to three group, just like below:

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
|schoolID|count(studentID)|count(teacherID)|sum(size)|sum(documentCount)|avg_totalScore|
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
|great   |               2|               2|      195|               314|         100.0|
|great   |               2|               2|      193|               330|          94.5|
|great   |               2|               2|      294|               285|          83.4|
|good    |               2|               2|      263|               415|          72.5|
|good    |               2|               2|      263|               415|          62.5|
|good    |               2|               2|      263|               415|          52.5|
|bad     |               2|               2|      263|               415|          49.8|
|bad     |               2|               2|      263|               415|          42.3|
|bad     |               2|               2|      263|               415|          32.5|
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+--------------+
```

In other words, I want to divide school into three groups according to their "avg_totalScore", respectively great school, good school, and bad school, the rate is 3:3:3 .

My solution is following :

```
val num = orderedDf.count()
val first_split_num = math.floor(num * (1.0/3))
val second_split_num = math.ceil(num * (2.0/3))
val accumu = SparkContext.getOrCreate(Configuration.getSparkConf).accumulator(0, "Group Num")
val rdd = orderedDf.map(row => {
  val group = {
    accumu match {
      case a: Accumulator[Int] if a.value <= first_split_num => "great"
      case b: Accumulator[Int] if b.value <= second_split_num => "good"
      case _ => "bad"
    }
  }
  accumu += 1
  Row(group, row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6))
})

val result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,orderedDf.schema)
```

The code above is ok, there is no any exception, But when I use :

```
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

or

```
result.show()
```

I get a ClassNotFound exception, I don't know the reason. Who can help me, Thank you very much!

Here is the details of exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 44.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 44.0 (TID 3644, node1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lancoo.ecbdc.business.ComparativeAnalysisBusiness$$anonfun$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The specific class-not-found is `com.lancoo.ecbdc.business.ComparativeAnalysisBusiness$$anonfun$1`, and given that you don't show the implementation of `orderedDf`, the chance of the issue being there is very high.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess the problem is in the map function, because map function is a transform operator, a lazy operator, so it is okay before some action operator execute. But I don't know where is error in map function.

Answer (score 0):

As a Spark newbie I *just* ran into this issue - it looks very much like you haven't actually submitted the jar containing your class to the executor node, so when you attempt to perform an action on the dataframe (which is distributed), the executors can't run the code because the class isn't found.

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lancoo.ecbdc.business.ComparativeAnalysisBusiness$$anonfun$1
```

The class loader could not load above mentioned class as per the exception. Could you provide more information how this class is used in your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, The code above posted is in this class, So I guess the problem is not ClassNotFound, but the anonymous function in this class.